# Leiningen missing test resources?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Leiningen provides a default directory for 'main' code, main resources, and test code, but nothing for test resources.

Coming from a maven background this is something I'd expect.

In that case, where should test resources live?  Or a larger question, what's the philosophical reason why it wouldn't need a test resources directory

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Test resources in Leiningen are managed using profiles. To set up a directory with test resources, you would add its path to the `:resource-paths` property of the `:test` profile (to make it available only to the `test` task) or `:dev` profile (to make it available to all dev tasks, e.g. `test`, `run`, `repl`, etc.)

Sample `project.clj` for a Maven-like project structure:

```
(defproject myproject "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  :source-paths ["src/main/clj"]
  :test-paths ["src/test/clj"]
  :resource-paths ["src/main/resources"]
  :dev {:resource-paths ["src/test/resources"]})
```

When the `:dev` profile is active, its `:resource-paths` values are merged with the `:resource-paths` from the base project, giving you what you're looking for.

See [the Leiningen docs](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/stable/doc/PROFILES.md) for more information on profiles.